# No Option To Get Angular Smart Table State With Visible Columns

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I'm just wondering if they have provided a options to make table columns show and hide as user preference and save it in table state and load it back when page refreshes.

```
ctrl.tableState()
```

upper code only brings the pagination,sorting and search objects as in current table state. How can i implement showing and hide table columns like in jquery Datatable and load it back from the table state object?

Comment: Worst case use ng-show or ng-class and store the state of columns yourself

Comment: @charlietfl That would be troublesome to write code for every table i have used. Decided to use Jquery Data Table instead

Comment: You can extend smart table but is not a quick simple answer. Am writing off top of my head but adding a directive that `require`'s the smart table controller would be start point...similar to the way the other sub directives are written

Comment: @charlietfl Yes i thought of it. But it will take much time to get over with it. So any way decided to go on with Jquery Data Table. Thanks for your help though :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to use Jquery Data Table instead with AngularJS ng-repeat